# Imagem aparece "quebrada" depois que mudou a versão do PHP

Tags: php, gd

atualmente mudei uma aplicação de máquina, com isso a imagem do código de barras não aparece mais. A versão do PHP desta máquina nova é mais recente, já tentei mudar a chamada da imagem mas nada acontece. Como poderia resolver?

```
   <?php
      echo "<IMG src='barras.php?num=" .$codigobarras." '>";             
   ?>
```

Código de barras (barras.php)

```
<?

Header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

$bf = 1;
$ab = 50;
if ($bf == "")
{
    $tamxt = 1;
    $tamxl = 3;
}
else
{
    $tamxt = $bf;
    $tamxl = ($bf * 2) + 1;
}   

if ($ab == "")
    $tamy = 50;
else
    $tamy = $ab;

$aux_len = strlen($num)%2;

if ($aux_len != 0)
    $aux_len = (strlen($num) + 1) / 2;
else
    $aux_len = strlen($num) / 2;

$aux_tamx = ((6 * $tamxt + 4 * $tamxl) * $aux_len) + (6 * $tamxt) + $tamxl;


$im = ImageCreate($aux_tamx, $tamy);

$white = ImageColorAllocate($im,255,255,255);
$black = ImageColorAllocate($im,0,0,0);

$x = 0;
$y = 0;

function add_wt()
{
    global $x, $y, $tamxt, $tamy, $white, $black, $im, $tamxl;
    ImageFilledRectangle($im, $x, $y, $x + $tamxt, $y + $tamy, $white);
    $x = $x + $tamxt;
}

function add_wl()
{
    global $x, $y, $tamxt, $tamy, $white, $black, $im, $tamxl;
    ImageFilledRectangle($im, $x, $y, $x + $tamxl, $y + $tamy, $white);
    $x = $x + $tamxl;
}

function add_bt()
{
    global $x, $y, $tamxt, $tamy, $white, $black, $im, $tamxl;
    ImageFilledRectangle($im, $x, $y, $x + $tamxt, $y + $tamy, $black);
    $x = $x + $tamxt;
}

function add_bl()
{
    global $x, $y, $tamxt, $tamy, $white, $black, $im, $tamxl;
    ImageFilledRectangle($im, $x, $y, $x + $tamxl, $y + $tamy, $black);
    $x = $x + $tamxl;   
}

function add_to_bar ($code)
{
    switch ($code)
    {
    case '00':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '01':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '02':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '03':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '04':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '05':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '06':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '07':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '08':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '09':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '10':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '11':
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '12':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '13':
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '14':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '15':
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '16':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '17':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '18':
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '19':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '20':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '21':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '22':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '23':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '24':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '25':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '26':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '27':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '28':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '29':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '30':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '31':
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '32':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '33':
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '34':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '35':
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '36':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '37':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '38':
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '39':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '40':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '41':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '42':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '43':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '44':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '45':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '46':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '47':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '48':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '49':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '50':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '51':
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '52':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '53':
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '54':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '55':
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '56':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '57':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '58':
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '59':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '60':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '61':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '62':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '63':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '64':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '65':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '66':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '67':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '68':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '69':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '70':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '71':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '72':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '73':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '74':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '75':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '76':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '77':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '78':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '79':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '80':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '81':
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '82':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '83':
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '84':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '85':
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '86':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '87':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '88':
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '89':
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '90':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '91':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '92':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '93':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '94':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '95':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '96':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '97':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;

    case '98':
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '99':
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bl();
        add_wl();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '100':     /* start */
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wt();
    break;

    case '101':     /* stop */
        add_bl();
        add_wt();
        add_bt();
        add_wl();
    break;
    }
}

add_to_bar("100");      /* Start */

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen ($num); $i = $i + 2)
{
    $cod = substr ($num, $i, 2);
    add_to_bar ($cod);
}

add_to_bar("101");      /* Stop */

//ImagePNG($im); 
ImageJpeg($im); 
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54601/discussion-on-question-by-deb-imagem-aparece-quebrada-depois-que-mudou-a-versa)

Answer (score 2):

Existem três possíveis problemas que podem ter causado a falha:

1. Você usou `<?` ao invés de `<?php`, recomendo que sempre use `<?php`.
2. Você usou `$num` ao invés de `$_GET['num']`

   Pra resolver este problema, adicione no inicio do script isto:

   ```
       <?php
       $num = $_GET['num'];

       Header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

       $bf = 1;
       $ab = 50;
       if ($bf == "")
       {
          $tamxt = 1;
          $tamxl = 3;
       }
       else
       {
          $tamxt = $bf;
          $tamxl = ($bf * 2) + 1;
       }
   ```
3. Biblioteca GD está desativada.

   A biblioteca GD é responsável pelas funções `imagecreate`, `imagecolorallocate`, etc. Pra ativar ela será necessário configurar no *php.ini*, procure no php.ini uma linha semelhante a está:

   ```
   ;extension=php_gd2.dll
   ```

   Remova o `;` do começo e salve o arquivo, se esta linha não existir então adicione isto ao arquivo:

   ```
   extension=php_gd2.dll
   ```

   Se estiver usando uma distribuição Debian ou Ubuntu (servidores linux) então você deve também executar está linha no terminal:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install php5-gd
   ```

   (No entanto acredito que o GD já esteja instalado, já que anteriormente funcionava).

   Após isto reinicie o servidor e teste novamente o script.

### "Depurando" o script

Se nada disto funcionar, então você pode tentar testar o seu arquivo pois pode ser um problema no teu servidor que só você poderá detectar, pra "depurar" o teu script faça o seguinte:

- Comente o `header` assim:

  ```
      <?php
      $num = $_GET['num'];

      //Header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
  ```

  - Abra o teu arquivo diretamente no web-browser/navegador sem usar o `<img>`, algo como:

    http://localhost/projeto/barra.php?num=1

    Provavelmente irá ter algum erro, informe este erro na sua pergunta ou comente aqui.

### Dica sobre HTML e PHP

O seu php está assim:

```
echo "<IMG src='barras.php?num=" .$codigobarras." '>";
```

Quando executado ele processa isto por exemplo:

```
<IMG src='barras.php?num=5 '>
```

Veja que ficou um espaço no final, apesar de não afetar o teu script, isto não parece certo. Também recomendo:

- Use apóstrofos para o PHP e aspas pro HTML
- Quando usar `echo` use `,` ao invés de pontos
- Use tags html em minusculo

Deve ficar assim:

```
echo '<img src="barras.php?num=', $codigobarras, '">';
```

Estas dicas não farão grande diferença, mas ajudam a tornar o código um pouco melhor pra trabalhar.

Comment: Sua resposta está perfeita, eu daria +1 se pudesse. Mas na verdade existem muito mais erros possíveis além desses.

Comment: @IvanFerrer obrigado, acredito que sim existam mais problemas, porém me parecem mais voltados ao como foi escrito o script, a minha resposta não é exata, mas tenta dar uma ideia de como ativar tudo "necessário" e ainda depurar o código, no entanto se notou algo a mais referente a configuração do html ou erro de sintaxe por favor nos forneça um resposta mais completa (pode ter certeza que já ter +1 de minha parte) :) Até mais

Answer (score -1):

Converti seu método em uma classe, veja se isso te ajuda:

**http://viper-7.com/BOyUrk**